# Em dash Utilization?

Tags: punctuation

> "—as you may have noticed!—"

I don't think what goes in em dashes should be a complete sentence. This seems to utilize a punctuation mark, like a complete sentence. It's not supposed to be a complete sentence, is it? "You" is a subject, "have" is a "verb". It seems to contain maybe a verb after that, "noticed", but there's no object?

Comment: There's no rule about what **must** be inside em-dashes.

Comment: May that seem a sentence, in there "as you may have noticed!"? I think em dashes, maybe, seem to place information in sentences. Maybe, what goes in em dashes don't seem like sentences. May that seem like one? It seems to contain a subject, a verb, and it may seem to contain verbs. It may not seem to contain an object? I think I maybe get, things like, imperatives may seem sentences, maybe not complete sentences, they seem to go like, maybe, "Go!"

Comment: Your questions would be far clearer if they contained absolutely zero instances of "may" or "maybe".

Comment: It would also help if you stopped using 'seem', at least until you learn what it means.  People have pointed out on at least three occasions that you're using it incorrectly.  This is the fourth, I guess.

Comment: less commas, too… or should that be less commas too?

Comment: @Tetsujin - And maybe fewer "maybes", too? By the way (to the O.P.), you seem pretty interested in the relationship between punctuation marks and complete sentences. As such, you might find [this ELU post](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105665) interesting. (Warning: Do not read the column in the answer unless you understand that much of it was written with some sarcasm.)

Answer (score 2):

This is a sentence fragment that uses an exclamation point to add emphasis. the em-dashes show that this quote is interjected between two other quotes (or possibly that the beginning and end of the quote were not heard). If you were writing a normal (non-emphatic) interjection, you would probably not use a period.

Consider:

> **Alice:** "We are out of money—"
>   **Bob:** "—as you may have noticed!—"
>   **Alice:** "—and cannot buy tickets."

And the non-emphatic version:

> **Alice:** "We are out of money—"
>   **Bob:** "—as you may have noticed—"
>   **Alice:** "—and cannot buy tickets."

The rest of the punctuation (the dashes and quotation marks) are sufficient to mark the phrase as separate from the other phrases. Also the phrase is meant to be taken as an addition to the outer sentence ("*We are out of money [...] and cannot by tickets.*"), so a period is not entirely appropriate. This exclamation point is used only to indicate tone of voice.

Comment: That seems interesting! I thank you! I guess "as you may have noticed!" gets specified an "interjection"? That seems interesting. It may not seem a complete sentence, it may not seem to contain an object. It may not seem a phrase, it may seem to contain a subject and verb. Maybe it seems a clause? I guess, interrogatives may seem like clauses, here and there?

Comment: "As you may have noticed" is a clause. I should also note that I am **not** using "interjection" here as a part of speech like *noun* or *verb*. I am using it as a general term for a sudden statement; that is, "something that has been interjected". (See: [*interject*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/interject): "*to say or mention suddenly, often in interrupting the remarks of another*".)

Comment: "The problem with the dash—as you may have noticed!—is that it discourages truly efficient writing." "—as you may have noticed!—" seems like a clause, not an interrogative? I may not get what clause it seems like. Like, main clauses seem to contain, maybe, an object. I thank you, apsillers.

Comment: This is a subordinate clause that begins with "*as*". (*Interrogative* mean "related to asking a question" (or, as a noun or adjective, a question-asking word like "when?" or "why?"). There are no interrogatives in the sentence you've provided; there are no questions being asked. Do you mean something else?)

Comment: It seems like a subordinate clause! I thank you! "As" maybe seems a "subordinate conjunction"? I guess it may get specified like "dependent clause", and may not seem a complete sentence, it may not seem to got an object. That seems what I get. I thank you!